# NullPointerException in a while loop using a Binary Tree node

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, while-loop, binary-tree

I am using a binary tree structure here. I am getting a "NullPointerException" from the line containing the while statement. I am completely confused about why that would be.

```
   BinaryTreeNode<CharData> currNode = theTree.findValue(data);

    // Move up the Binary Tree to create code. 
    while(currNode.getParent() != null) {
        // The loop does some stuff that doesn't
        // affect what is assigned to currNode.

        // Move to the parent node for the next iteration.
        currNode = currNode.getParent();

    } // End the while loop.

    return code; // Return the string of binary code.
```

Find value is a method from my BinaryTree class that searches for and finds the node containing specific data. I know this works from testing it separately outside of this implementation.

Comment: One way or the other, `currNode` is `null`, so there is something wrong with your `findValue(...)` method.

Comment: And what does findValue return when the value is not found?

Comment: 1) is it possible for `findvalue` to return `null` and 2) what if `data` isn't found?  Wouldn't that return `null`?

Comment: I figured it out. After spending about an hour thinking about it, I decided to post. About five seconds later, I figured it out. I had to add another findValue method specific for this class since in this class, I was implementing the BinaryTreeNodes with data type CharData. The problem was that I was creating a new object of CharData to pass to the findValue method, so java said this object and that object are not "equal" although they may contain the same values. I had to create a findValue method that specifically found the node with a certain char value in its CharData.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why the while-loop statement can throw a `NPE` is, when `currNode` is `null`. I suspect `findValue()` returned `null`.

I guess one fix (when you care about the topmost node) would be:

```
while(currentNode != null) {
    rootNode = currentNode;
    currentNode = currentNode.getParent();
}
```

Or the typical pattern which relies on boolean shortcut evaluation:

```
while(curentNode != null && currentNode.getParent() != null)
```

Or my prefered solution using guards:

```
if (currentNode == null)
   throw NotFound(); // or return something

while(curentNode.getParent() != null) {
```

Comment: I figured it out. My findValue() method worked when I was trying to find a simple integer or char, nothing fancy. In this case, I was trying to find the node that contained a CharData object which was a class I created with a character and how many times it occurred in a given string. By trying to use findValue(), I was making java search for an object that technically didn't exist in the binary tree since I created a new instance of it to pass to the findValue() method. I created a different class that did essentially the same thing as findValue(), but took into account the CharData type.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the code:

```
BinaryTreeNode<CharData> currNode = theTree.findValue(data);
```

I guess, `currNode` is getting some value if `findValue()` able to search data else it is returning NULL values.

When it returns a NULL value it will throw NPE.
To avoid it, you can modify your code a little bit.

```
while(currNode != null  && currNode.getParent != null) {
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: I figured out the issue. see what I commented above.